# How to retrieve full size user profile photo now that GooglePlus is deprecated?

Tags: ruby, google-api-ruby-client

Our service implemented code in 2015 to pull original photo of user profiles from the GooglePlus API using the ruby gem google-api-client

And although we can *still* pull photos for a lot of the older accounts even with GooglePlus having been deprecated since 2019, we are seeing issues with newer google accounts when making the request, encountering unauthorized_client errors for these newer accounts.

We have tried using the directory api to pull user photos instead,

(see:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_photo
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users.photos/get
)

but for some reason google designed this to only pull a 96x96 thumbnail of the user profile photo, resulting in blurry images when enlarged to larger size.

Is there a way to pull the original profile photo via the directory user api?  or is there a different api or flow that we are suppose to use now to retrieve user profile pictures, now that we can no longer rely on the GooglePlus service?